# Laravel unable to recognize model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I just started trying Laravel, but I'm having issues getting through the [quickstart guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick), specifically using the User model. Everything works for me in the guide until I try to employ the User model to access the database and display entries in a view. When I try to access public/users/ in the browser, I'm met with a page that says, **Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**. What's the matter with my code?

- I've set up the database with correct username/pw
- I created a table called 'users' using the migrate command
- The table's been populated with a couple entries
- I also have a view file, **users.blade.php**, that looks like this:

  ```
  @extends('layout')

  @section('content')
      @foreach($users as $user)
          <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
      @endforeach
  @stop
  ```
- Here is my entire **routes.php** file. I should note that when users.blade.php was just static html, it would show up fine in my browser when my routes file just had `return View::make('users')`:

  ```
  <?php

  Route::get('/', function()
  {
      return View::make('hello');
  });

  Route::get('users',function()
  {
      $users = User::all();

      return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);

      //return View::make('users');
  });
  ```
- And here is my **User.php** model:

(This was auto-generated when I started the project)

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

I also tried just having my User.php model look like

```
class User extends Eloquent {}
```

as the quickstart guide says, but that also results in the same error.

Here's my **composer.json** file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: All depends on your autoloader. It may not be able to find the class in question. What do you have in composer.json?

Comment: Oh yes, I should add that I've tried the commands: composer dump-autoload and php artisan dump-autoload, but that hasn't resolved the problem. I'll add my composer.json file as well.

Comment: Have you also turned debug mode on? In your app.php config file, set debug to true for more detailed error messages

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was wondering how to get more helpful error messages. It's saying: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'. The problem was I only changed the app/config/local/database.php file with my username/pw, but not app/config/database.php. Now it works, thanks!